# Combine two divs in one .html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with content

```
<div class="takemyvalue">Blah</div>
```

and this bit that fills out a third

```
$('.filldiv').val(  $('.takemyvalue').html());
```

How can I join the value from another div as well to go into filldiv:

```
 <div class="takemyvalue2">Boo</div>
```

So the output would be 'Blah Boo'?

Comment: Add the resulting `div`

Comment: simply concat the html of both divs like $('.filldiv').val(  $('.takemyvalue').html()+$('.takemyvalue2').html());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the text of each `div` and combine them in the new div(with class  `.filldiv`) using jquery [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or .[**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```js
$('.filldiv').text($('.takemyvalue').text() + $('.takemyvalue2').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="takemyvalue">Blah</div>

<div class="takemyvalue2">Boo</div>

<div class="filldiv"></div>
```

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of select elements, it
>   returns null when no option is selected and an array containing the
>   value of each selected option when there is at least one and it is
>   possible to select more because the multiple attribute is present.

Also as mention in comments you can use [**.append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to keep `.filldiv` content:

```js
$('.filldiv').append($('.takemyvalue').text() + $('.takemyvalue2').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="takemyvalue">Blah</div>
<div class="takemyvalue2">Boo</div>
<div class="filldiv">Another content</div>
```

Comment: This time you just answered :) Don't wanna wait!

Comment: Add `append` as an option, if the `filldiv` has content that OP may not want to replace